# BizTalk UDDI Services Installation

Tags: installation, biztalk, uddi

Is it possible to install UDDI Services for BizTalk ESB Toolkit on Windows 7 32-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the dev tools and SDK for UDDI can be installed on Windows 7.